# external style sheet in pug template will not load

Tags: javascript, css, pug, pugjs

I am unable to figure out how to get a style sheet to load in pug. I have tried every which way I can think of. and have searched extensively on Google. This seems like such a silly problem, but I have already wasted so much time trying to figure it out.

My file structure is as follows

```
/main
    server.js
    package.json
    /views
        layout.pug
        main.pug
    /public
        style.css
```

In all of the following examples I have tried to reference the file in these ways:

- `href="../public/style.css"`
- `href="./public/style.css"`
- `href="/public/style.css"`
- `href="public/style.css"`

and

- `href="/style.css"`

I have tried:

---

1) link element in main.pug

```
    //- daytime page
    extends layout.pug
    block styles
        link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/style.css")
```

---

2) In the layout.pug **using `include`**

```
//- layout
doctype
html
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    block title
      title country
    block styles
  body
    style.
      include ../public/day.css
```

*AS WELL AS inside the header*

---

3) In layout.pug using

```
//- layout
doctype
html
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    block title
      title country
    block styles
      link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/style.css")
body
```

---

**Inspect Source**

When I inspect the source of the pug files that contain the pug  element. the browser shows that the link has been rendered correctly inside the  parent.

[image: screenshot of firefox inspect element]

**css does load when I write it directly in the pug file like so:**

```
style.
    selector{
        rule
        rule
}
```

---

I can not keep my css inline, and I can not use html directly in the pug file (assignment rules). Why are my stylesheets not loading?

---

Specs:

- Firefox 56.0
- Ubuntu 16.04
- pug 2.0
- express 4.16.2

Comment: Some browsers don't accept the hot load of css. You should try a `.createElement('link')` with a `.onload` event

Comment: Did you ever figure out why? I am having the same problem :/

Answer (score 7):

Check if you have set public folder as static inside of server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

then in pug files add

```
head
block styles
  link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
style
     include css.css
```

It's working for me and I hope will help you , read here https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html

Answer (score 2):

For pub version 2.* and higher, use the below code,

```
html
    head
        style
             include ./style.css
    body
```